# CSS Required Indicator Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what in the CSS is causing the `*` to display below the textbox when I add the class **tiny** to the **div**

```
<div class="editor-field tiny required-indicator">
```

Check out the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfqqmmfn/

If the class **tiny** is removed then the `*` display after the textbox like expected. I'm still learning CSS so any help would be great. I know it has to be something simple but I can't find the issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfqqmmfn/2/

I changed `.required-indicator:after` (the little asterisk) to this:

```
.required-indicator:after
{
    content: "*";
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Red;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:calc(100% + 10px);
    top:0;
}
```

And added `position:relative;` to your `.tiny` class.
Relative position to the parent (.tiny) lets me use position:absolute on its :after pseudo-element (which behaves as its child).

You had your asterisk pseudo-element on `position:relative;` so by giving that item the `.tiny` class, you set its width to 135px (with !important, too) thus stopping the little asterisk from fitting in there.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the explanation. I know just enough CSS to get by but I need to learn a lot more. I knew it was something with the width but I couldn't figure out what was causing it not to fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this

```
form div.tiny {
  width: 120px !important;
}
```

it overwrites the built-in rule that causes your problem (making the input field containers too narrow to allow the asteriks next to it). You can try and use different width settings.

https://jsfiddle.net/zLoqy3py/